# What is the debian equivalent to this repoquery command?

Tags: debian, apt, yum, rpm

What is the debian equivalent to this repoquery command?

```
repoquery --repofrompath="abc,http://path/to/repo" --repoid=abc -q mypkg 
--qf %{NAME}_%{VERSION}_%{RELEASE}_%{ARCH}_%{BUILDTIME}_%{PACKAGER}_%{LOCATION}
```

This will ignore any repos specified under /etc/yum.repos.d, and list the requested information for the latest available version of mypkg in the repo specified in repofrompath.

So far, I have found

```
apt-cache showpkg mypkg
```

but I am not sure how to use the -c config-file option to simulate the effect of repofrompath above.

Comment: If you're expecting an answer from a Debian user, you may want to tell them what that command is supposed to do, or even better, what information you're actually after.

Answer (score 2):

You could give aptitude a try. Example:

```
root@printserver:/root# aptitude search --display-format '%p_%V_%m ' --disable-columns  "tcsh"
tcsh_6.17.02-4_Thomas Lange <lange@debian.org>
```

Where:

```
%p = Package Name
%V = Version
%m = Maintainer
```

---

Examples with the `--target-release option`

```
root@printserver:~# aptitude search --display-format '%p_%V_%m ' --disable-columns  "linux-image-amd64" --target-release squeeze
linux-image-amd64_2.6.32+29_Debian Kernel Team <debian-kernel@lists.debian.org> 
root@printserver:~# aptitude search --display-format '%p_%V_%m ' --disable-columns  "linux-image-amd64" --target-release squeeze-backports
linux-image-amd64_3.2+46~bpo60+1_Debian Kernel Team <debian-kernel@lists.debian.org>
```

Comment: thanks. can I specify the target repo as part of the command?

Comment: `--target-release`. Editing my answer ;)

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to provide an inline definition of target-release so that the overall command doesn't depend on files under /etc/apt?